# Python 3, Calling a Function Properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I'm quite new to Python, kind of new to programming and I'm having trouble creating a proper "loop".

```
def gameLoop():
    print('1')
    if ageInt == 2:
        gamePlay = '{}'.format(input("Would you like to play a game?\n"))
    else:
        sys.exit(0)

    time.sleep(1)
    if any([gamePlay == 'yes', gamePlay == 'sure']):
        print('you are playing a game')
    elif gamePlay == 'maybe':
            gamePlay = '{}'.format(input("C'mon, let,'s play...\n"))
            time.sleep(1)
            gameLoop()
```

I realize a lot of this code may be sloppy, but I'm trying to call gameLoop, so if they answer "maybe" it returns to gameLoop. Why doesn't the last line of the code return to the first line?

Edit to include full code:

```
import time
import sys

name = input('What is your name?\n')
print('Hello, %s!' % name)
age = int (input('how old are you?\n'))
print('Your age is: %s' % age, ' and your name is: %s' % name)
ageInt = int (1)

def gameLoop():
    print('gameloopworks')
    if ageInt == 2:
        gamePlay = '{}'.format(input("Would you like to play a game?\n"))
    else:sys.exit(0)

    time.sleep(1)
    if any([gamePlay == 'yes', gamePlay == 'sure']):
        print('you are playing a game')
    elif gamePlay == 'maybe':
            gamePlay = '{}'.format(input("C'mon, let,'s play...\n"))
            time.sleep(1)
            print('elif works')
            gameLoop()

if age < 18:
    print(name, 'sorry you\'re too young')
    ageInt = 1

else:
    print(name, 'you are totally blankable')
    ageInt = 2
    gameLoop()
```

Comment: What is `ageInt`? [mcve] please...

Comment: is `time.sleep(1)` ... part of the function? If so you are attempting a recursive call, not a loop

Comment: And is goes back to the first line as far as I can tell. Again [mcve] please.../

Comment: sorry I did not include the full code example I will edit the post now with the full example. Answer below is correct though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Your code works. A recursive call gameLoop() is in progress. Or I 
>   didn't understand the question.
> ```

```
  What is your name?
  Vladmir
  Hello, Vladmir!
  how old are you?
  45
  Your age is: 45  and your name is: Vladmir
  Vladmir you are totally blankable
  gameloopworks
  Would you like to play a game?
  maybe
  C'mon, let,'s play...
  OK
  elif works
  gameloopworks
  Would you like to play a game?
  maybe
  C'mon, let,'s play...
  OK
  elif works
  gameloopworks
  Would you like to play a game?
  maybe
  C'mon, let,'s play...
  ys
  elif works
  gameloopworks
  Would you like to play a game?
  yes
  you are playing a game
  Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I'm so dumb; I was wondering why it wasn't asking if you wanted to play again. Without realizing that I was asking for an input before that happened. facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing recursion instead of a loop; you are basically calling the same function each time, but the values of each call will not persist into the next because of variable scoping (a little more advanced than what you want right now, but just in case).

Try using a `while` loop and that should work much better for your purpose.

```
keep_playing = True
while keep_playing:
    if <condition to stop>:
        keep_playing = False
    else:
        # keep game
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be this

```
def gameLoop():
while True:
    if ageInt == 2:
        gamePlay = '{}'.format(input("Would you like to play a game?\n"))
    else:
        sys.exit(0)

    if any([gamePlay == 'yes', gamePlay == 'sure']):
        print('you are playing a game')
    elif gamePlay == 'maybe':
        gamePlay = '{}'.format(input("C'mon, let,'s play...\n"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameLoop()
```